# Trac - Automatically Closing Old Tickets

Tags: trac

Is there a trac plugin for automatically closing tickets that have remained open for a certain time period?

I noticed this functionality on Pidgin's trac but have been unable to find a plugin that allows this.

Comment: Has this been resolved for you meanwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a ready-made solution, but personally I found the [PendingTicketPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/PendingTicketPlugin) very helpful as a starting point for developing my own solution for automatic closing of tickets after a given time using a Python script called via cron.

Comment: Please extend your question, if you need more specific guidance. I could even dig up the working script for you a reference when needed.